# Export SCSS files from a shared lib in NX so they can be used in apps

Tags: sass, nrwl, nomachine-nx

I have a Monorepo build with `NX v16.1.0`. There are one React app and one `shared-ui` lib inside. My goal is to find a way to export `scss` files from the shared-ui folder so I can use them in my client's applications `.scss files`. Example: In a CSS module file in my React app to be able to apply the styles as such `@import "@shared-ui/global-colors.module.scss"`. Is there a way to do such thing in `NX v16.1.0` right now?

Comment: Were you able to find solution this?